# How many ways can you choose 15 ice creams from 5 different types of ice cream? Every type has 15 ice-creams except type 1 which has 2.

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, combinations

There are no restrictions other than the limit of type 1 ice-cream.

Initially I assumed there were 5 options for 2 of the 15 slots and that if they were used up I would have 4 options for the remaining 13 slots:

$5^{2} + 4^{13}$

I also tried the reverse where I assumed I had 5 options for all 15 slots and then tried subtracting all the cases where type 1 existed more than twice but I couldn't come to an answer.

Also, as order isn't important I imagine having to divide by some combination $5!$ and $4!$ somewhere to account for this.

Comment: Are there any restrictions like there has to be at least one of each type?

Comment: no restrictions with the exception of only being 2 units of type 1 ice cream

Comment: ok then it is a standard star and bar problem.

Comment: none of my study notes or even my textbook mention star and bar. It seems like such a nice way to solve these problems

Comment: Yes, just be sure not to apply it ever to calculate probability.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We seek the number of solutions to $a+b+c+d+e=15$ with all numbers nonnegative and $a\le2$. This can be solved by setting $a=0,1,2$, counting the possibilities for each case by stars and bars and summing:
$$a=0\implies N=\binom{15+3}3=816$$
$$a=1\implies N=\binom{14+3}3=680$$
$$a=2\implies N=\binom{13+3}3=560$$
$$816+680+560=2056$$

Comment: Could you please explain the 3's and also why you go 15 14 and 13

Comment: @DamianJacobs This is all stars and bars. When I apply this I like to actually write out the number of stars ($13$ to $15$, after we fix $a$ and subtract) and bars ($3$ since we have four remaining variables).

Comment: Thank you so much for clarifying. Stars and bars or balls and urns as I read somewhere now, isnt covered anywhere in my module. Seems strange considering how useful it appears to be.